# Stackoverflowerror / Unresolved Object Exception with Hibernate, Collections and Session.refresh(...)

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

In my current project, I'm using Hibernate 3. The tool I'm working on connects to a MS SQL Server Database. The tool is installed on two different Machines, both connect to the same Database.

On the first machine I'm altering an object that contains a collection. On the second Machine I'm using session.refresh(...) to see the Changes made on the first Machine.

When I add an Object to the collection and refresh, I get a Stackoverflowerror. When I remove an Object from the collection and refresh, I get an UnresolvedObjectException.

```
session.evict(...)
session.get(...)
```

seems to work. But `session.refresh(...)`. Why?

Here is a full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.<init>(JtdsStatement.java:129)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.<init>(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:99)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.prepareStatement(ConnectionJDBC2.java:2456)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.prepareStatement(ConnectionJDBC2.java:2414)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.proxy.ConnectionProxy.prepareStatement(ConnectionProxy.java:394)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1573)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:71)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:65)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:434)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:415)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:873)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:607)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:298)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1121)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:588)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:71)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:65)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:434)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:415)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:873)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:607)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:298)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1121)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:588)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:71)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:65)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:434)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:415)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:873)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:607)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:298)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1121)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:588)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:71)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:65)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:434)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:415)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:873)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:607)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:298)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1121)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:588)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:71)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:65)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:434)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:415)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:873)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:607)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:298)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1121)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:588)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:71)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:65)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:434)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:415)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:873)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:607)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:298)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1121)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:588)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:71)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:65)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:434)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:415)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:873)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:607)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:298)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1121)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:588)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:71)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:65)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:434)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:415)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:873)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:607)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:298)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1121)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:588)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:71)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:65)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:434)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:415)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:873)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:607)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:298)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1121)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:588)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:71)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:65)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:434)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:415)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:873)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:607)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:298)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1121)
```

Comment: Looks like you have a circular reference in one of your objects. Can you post your hibernate object definition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA. Stackoverflow on cascade merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727871/jpa-stackoverflow-on-cascade-merge)

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

The solution for me was not to use `CascadeType.REFRESH` (or `CascadeType.ALL`) for any bidirectional associations.

## Background

I had the same issue when I used `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on the parent side of  the `@OneToMany`, with the child also having a `@ManyToOne` relation to this parent, e.g.:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "hospital", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

The same happened when I used just `cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH`.

Refreshing the parent also refreshes the child, which refreshes the parent, which refreshes the child ...