# JPA. Stackoverflow on cascade merge

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, stack-overflow, cascade

Here is my JPA structure:

Movie (look at cascade types):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movie")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "movie_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    //@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "primaryKey.movie") //stack overflow
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.movie") //works fine
    private List<Rating> ratings;
    ....
}
```

Rating:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rating")
@AssociationOverrides({@AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.movie", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "imdb_user_id"))})
public class Rating {
    @EmbeddedId
    private RatingId primaryKey = new RatingId();

    @Column(name = "rating_value")
    private Integer ratingValue;
    .....
}
```

RatingId:

```
@Embeddable
public class RatingId implements Serializable{
    @ManyToOne
    private Movie movie;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}
```

When I call `entityManager.merge(Movie movie)` with `CascadeType.ALL` I get the StackOverflowError. If remove cascading, merge call doesn't throw the error. Where may be a problem?

I think this problem related to composite primary key. There is no error when `merge` performed on another entities with the same one-to-many relationship, but without composite id.

Comment: If somebody want, I can provide stack trace.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to provide a stack trace.

Comment: Can you show us your JPA code that trigger this error ? (creation of your entity + EntityManager api usage)

Comment: @AlexandreJacob I actually solved this problem by adding `FetchType.LAZY` in right places. Later I'll write the answer.

Comment: **Be careful :** changing your loading strategy may not be the best way to correct your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StackOverflow was caused by cyclic relations. To avoid exception I marked keys in many-to-many table as `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`.

That's how my tables look after modifications: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32544519/2089491